# Eclipse PyDev doesn't shut down interpreter when you click the little red button

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

Seems that even after unchecking the option in the PyDev/Debug preferenecs pane to launch in the background, once it's launched I have to go to task manager to kill the python process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell when working with Django you need to add `runserver --noreload` to your program argument in Run > Run... menu

Answer (score 1):

This often happens when you're using something like cherrypy/django and the process restarts after you've changed a python file while it's running. When this happens, I think the process is different but still using the same output console and thus won't be killed when you press the red button.

I'm not sure there's a way of fixing it, except for disabling auto-restarting in the web framework etc.